signer privilege escalated when initial PDA
  for warrior_card_usage_ai in &ctx.remaining_accounts[0..warrior_cards_usage_len] {
        if warrior_card_usage_ai.data_is_empty() {
            msg!("creating warrior card usage account");
            let rent_lamports = rent.minimum_balance(warrior_card_usage_data_len);
            let cpi_accounts = CreateAccount {
                from: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                to: (*warrior_card_usage_ai).clone(),
            };
            let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                cpi_accounts
            );
            msg!("Expected data length: {}", warrior_card_usage_data_len);
            msg!("Minimum rent: {}", rent_lamports);

            create_account(
                cpi_context,
                rent_lamports,
                u64::try_from(warrior_card_usage_data_len).unwrap(),
                ctx.program_id
            )?;
        }
        let warrior_cards_usage: Account<WarriorCardsUsage> =
            Account::try_from(warrior_card_usage_ai)?;
        warrior_cards_usages.push(warrior_cards_usage);
    }

That is my test code
   let [warriorCardsUsageTracker] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        attacker.publicKey.toBuffer(),
        remainingAccountsMock[2].pubkey.toBuffer(),
        Buffer.from("warritor_cards_usage_tracker"),
      ],
      program.programId
    );

and pass it as remain account. but get FAy8Uq39nNtspAtnATYj4b543HjrVb9zTdKeYho5pqUZ's signer privilege escalated

failed: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account"

I think as you are doing create account instruction for PDA (warriorCardsUsageTracker), we need to call invoke_signed or CpiContext::new_with_signer if we do cpi with anchor.  We need to use same seeds in instruction to create PDA which were used to derive PDA in first place.
Code should look something like
//attacker_info is attacker.publicKey.to_account_info()
//remainingAccountsMock[2]_info() is remainingAccountsMock[2].to_account_info()
//b"warritor_cards_usage_tracker" is string in bytes
//when we call findProgramAddressSync, we get [PDA, bump]. We get bump from here

let seeds = &[&[attacker_info().clone(), remainingAccountsMock[2]_info().clone(),b"warritor_cards_usage_tracker", bytemuck::bytes_of(&bump)][..]];
let cpi_context = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            cpi_accounts,
            seeds
        );

